# Unicode issue on Careers 2 employer view

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, unicode, cv

On "employer view" page in Careers 2, there is an issue with unicode user name rendering.

See the screenshot (green is correct, red is incorrect):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the report.  We're tracking it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed at some point.  Just doing a little housecleaning.